# Sonar exclusions don't decrease the number of violations. All it does it decrease the number of lines

Tags: sonarqube

I am using Sonar v.3.5.

I have got a couple of questions:
1) Source File Exclusions. Two ways to specify what to exclude: Web and sonar-properties file.
Question: Which is more prevalent?

2) When I add exclusions (be it web or sonar properties), as a result it decreases the number of source code lines. It does not decrease the number of violations. 
Question: How do I exclude some files in my project so that they don't participate in violations?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am attaching a link. Please look at. There is a plugin named Switch off violations. You can download it. This plugin is only available for old SonarQube versions till 4.0. 
**http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin**

***PS: If you find this post useful please like it.***